# Excel VBA Loops & For each (by row)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

I'm currently building a Web Scraper to check patient eligibility using Excel VBA and the Selenium web driver. I've gotten stuck try to figure out how reference each row in my data set. Currently I'm able to reference the first row of my data but not the next:
[User Input Output Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YEPM.png)
EX.

Here's the code:

```
Sub WebScraper()
Dim driver As New IEDriver
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
website = Elig_Check_Form.Website_CBX.Text
UserName = Elig_Check_Form.Username_TXT.Text
Password = Elig_Check_Form.Password_TXT.Text
LName = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
FName = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
DOB = Format(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value, "MM/DD/YYYY") 
DOS = Format(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value, "MM/DD/YYYY")
EligStart = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value 
EligEnd = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value
EligStat = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value
WebsiteURL = "https://healthid.optum.com/tb/app/index.html?TARGET=https%3A2F%2Fprovider-linkhealth.unitedhealthcareonline.com%2Fb2c%2FLoginAction.do3Ftype%3DTmV0c2NhcGUjNS4wIChXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDYuMTsgV09XNjQ7IFRyaWRlbnQvNy4wOyBTTENDMjsgLk5FVCBDTFIgMi4wLjUwNzI3OyAuTkVUIENMUiAzLjUuMzA3Mjk7IC5ORVQgQ0xSIDMuMC4zMDcyOTsgLk5FVDQuMEM7IC5ORVQ0LjBFOyBydjoxMS4wKSBsaWtlIEdlY2tvI2ZhbHNlIzEx&relyingAppId=UHO60026#/login"
driver.Get WebsiteURL
driver.Window.Maximize
driver.FindElementById("userNameId_input").SendKeys (UserName) 'Reads Username
driver.FindElementById("passwdId_input").SendKeys (Password) 'Reads password
driver.FindElementById("SignIn").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
On Error GoTo PasswordErr
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[7]/div/a").Click

On Error Resume Next
driver.FindElementByName("AGREE").Click
'On Error GoTo 0
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[12]/div/a/div/h3").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
driver.FindElementByName("save").Click
 On Error GoTo ChooseProvider

'Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iFib, 1))
 Do While i < 1000 And Format(LName) <> vbNullString
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 For Each rw In sh.Rows


 driver.FindElementById("NameDateOfBirth-searchoptions").Click
 driver.FindElementById("last-name-[0]").SendKeys (LName) 
 driver.FindElementById("first-name-[0]").SendKeys (FName)
 driver.FindElementById("date-of-birth-[0]").SendKeys (DOB)
 driver.FindElementById("service-start-[0]").SendKeys (DOS)
 driver.FindElementById("search-button").Click
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
 On Error GoTo NotFound
 Sheets(1).Cells(i, 12).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='patient-     provider-information-section']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/p").Text
 Sheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='patient-provider-information-section']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/span[1]/h3").Text
 Sheets(1).Cells(i, 10).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='insurance-information-section']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/p").Text
 Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value = Left(driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='insurance-information-section']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/p").Text, 10)
 Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value = Right(driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='insurance-information-section']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/p").Text, 10)
 If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value >= Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value Or Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value < Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value Then
 Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = "Eligible"
 Else: Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = "Not Eligible"


 Exit For

 End If
 driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ng-app']/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span").Click
 i = i + 1


 Next rw
 Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The follow variables needed to be moved to after the do while statement

```
 LName = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
 FName = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
 DOB = Format(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value, "MM/DD/YYYY") 
 DOS = Format(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value, "MM/DD/YYYY")
 EligStart = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value 
 EligEnd = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value
 EligStat = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value
 i = 2
```

I also used a For loop instead of a do while loop. I can post the whole code if needed.